# How to bind value to each list item in Vue to toggle the images

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to toggle between the 2 images by triggering a function on click event, as shown below, how do I apply the same idea to different list items to **toggle the images individually for each item**? right now, all the list items same image because of one global value i.e val

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      val:true,
        selectedImg:"",
        checked: "@/assets/images/check.png",
        unchecked: "@/assets/images/uncheck.png",
        items: [
           { message: 'laundry' },
           { message: 'cooking' },
           { message: 'cleaning'}
          ]
    }
  },

  methods: {
   myfunc () {
          this.val = (this.val === true ? false : true) 
           
          if(this.val === true) {
            this.selectedImg = this.checked
          }  else  {
            this.selectedImg = this.unchecked
          }
      },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   <ul>
     <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.message">
       <button @click="myfunc"><img :src="selectedImg"/></button>
         {{ item.message }}  
     </li>
   </ul>
   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should move `selectedImg` and `val` into items objects and pass item to `myfunc` function.
You can also look at the answer in [codepen](https://codepen.io/burhansavci/pen/YzrppbE).

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
        checked: "@/assets/images/check.png",
        unchecked: "@/assets/images/uncheck.png",
        items: [
           { message: 'laundry', selectedImg:"" , val:true},
           { message: 'cooking', selectedImg:"", val:true},
           { message: 'cleaning', selectedImg:"", val:true}
          ]
    }
  },

  methods: {
   myfunc (item) {
          item.val = (item.val === true ? false : true) 
           
          if(item.val === true) {
            item.selectedImg = this.checked
          }  else  {
            item.selectedImg = this.unchecked
          }
      },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   <ul>
     <li v-for="item in items" :key="item.message">
       <button @click="myfunc(item)"><img :src="item.selectedImg"/></button>
         {{ item.message }}  
     </li>
   </ul>
   
</div>
```

Comment: Or you can even extract the logic to a new component of a custom checkbox :)